# How do I know if an array list of objects contain a certain string?

Tags: java

I made a method that search through an array list of objects. Then if the searchKey is found in the array list it will print this certain item.

Here is how I iterate through the array list if it contains the searchKey, but I just realized that it is impossible to compare a string and an object.

```
for(int x = 0; x < Student.students.size(); x ++){
    if(Student.students.contains(searchKey))
        System.out.print(Student.students.get(x));
}
```

Here's how I create the constructor and array list.

```
String firstName, lastName, course, yearLevel, gender;
    
    Student(String firstName, String lastName, String course, String yearLevel, String gender)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.course = course;
        this.yearLevel = yearLevel;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    static ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

Comment: please share the List instanciation and class of the object into it

Comment: what are you searching for? first name, last name, course, ... or gender? any of these? exact or partial match?

Answer (score 2):

You need to compare the one property; also you can use a for-each loop to simplify the code

```java
for(Student s : Student.students){
    if(s.getName().equals(searchKey))
        System.out.print(s);
}
```

---

Note :

When you use a condition `Student.students.contains(searchKey)` in a loop, and it doesn't use the iteration variable that means there is a problem

Comment: I posted how I create the list. I also try the method you just mentioned, but it wont work as it is still comparing a string to an object

Comment: @SillyBean: No, it's comparing the *name* of the student to the search key...

Comment: You can also use a stream, `students.stream().filter(s -> searchKey.equals(s.getName()).forEach(System.out::println)`.

Comment: @SillyBean what is `searchKey` a string or a Student ?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined what 'contains' means here but I'm going to assume that it means a Student contains the key if it appears as a substring in any of its String members.  So let's start with a method that does that.  We can define this as part of the Student class itself.

```
public class Student {
  .... other stuff ....
  /**
   * Return true if any of the properties of this Student
   * contain the given substring, false otherwise
   */
  public boolean contains(String s) {
    // consider addressing null cases - omitting for simplicity
    return firstName.contains(s) ||
      lastName.contains(s) ||
      course.contains(s) ||
      yearLevel.contains(s) ||
      gender.contains(s);
  }
}
```

Now you can iterate over your List and invoke this method to find the matches.  Note that you need to handle the case that multiple Students may match a given search key (or none may match).  So I would suggest collecting the results in a separate List.  One does not generally iterate over Lists via the index.  This example uses an enhanced for-loop (aka for-each).

```
public List<Student> findMatches(List<Student> students, String key) {
  List<Student> found = new ArrayList<>();
  for (Student s : students) {
    if (s.contains(key)) {
      found.add(s);
    }
  }
  return found;
}
```

This is a good case for using the Stream API.

```
public List<Student> findMatches(List<Student> students, String key) {
  return students.stream()
      .filter(s -> s.contains(key))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```